# How to ensure randomatic creates a unqiue identifier?

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb

I'm using randomatic npm to store id to mongoDB as mongo only creates a long objectID which can not be used for invoice numbers. My current model is:

```
orders: [
  {
    orderReference: { type: String },
    orderStatus: { type: String },
    orderType: { type: String },
    orderDate: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    itemDetails: { type: String },
    purchaseOrder: {
      orderReference: { type: String },
      orderStatus: { type: String },
      orderType: { type: String },
      orderDate: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
      itemDetails: { type: String },
    },
    thirdPartyOrder: {
      orderReference: { type: String },
      orderType: { type: String },
      orderDate: { type: Date },
      itemDetails: { type: String },
    },
    platformRevenue: {
      orderReference: { type: String },
      orderType: { type: String },
      orderDate: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
      itemDetails: { type: String }
    }
  }
],
```

In the current model how do I check/query that the ID that is currently in other orders are not duplicate and actually unique. Because randomatic doesn't create a unique ID by itself. It just creates a random ID whereas in my use case I want a unique 4 DIGIT NUMBERIC ID for orderReference.

Is there a possibility that four-digit random unique ids will finish one day and I should rather create sequential IDs instead which an increment of +1?

What is the industry standard of creating IDs for orderReferencing. I have mostly seen 4 to 6 digit number IDs on all the invoices I have received in my life.

Please help and suggest the best possible use-case.

Answer (score 0):

I would rather use your second suggestion, sequential IDs with increments.

While it is possible to use randoms, you are likely to check if a specific ID is already in the database before inserting, in which case you have to generate new IDs.

What's more, with a sequential version you will be able to keep a (approximate) track on the invoice / number of invoice.

The limit will be 10.000 different IDs either way (including 0).

Hope it helps!

Comment: The point remains how do I check with this structure? Had the referenceOrder ID be stored in the main document ObjectID it would have been possible.